# How to connect to ec2 ubuntu instance after clearing routing table

Tags: ubuntu, networking, amazon-ec2

I ran the command:  `sudo ip route flush table main` on my ssh shell on my ec2 ubuntu instance. Now I can no longer connect to the server either by ssh or any other means. Is there a way to restore connection by say, the aws console?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by just rebooting the ec2 instance from the aws console. I was then able to log back in via ssh, and the web servers inside became reachable again.